# Smooch NPM package not installing JS file

Tags: smooch

I am trying to integrate smooch into my React app via an npm install, but the smooch directory in my node_modules does not include any JS files upon installation. Using smooch with the scripts works, though. What am I doing wrong that the smooch directory in node_modules does not include the JS file?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in v4.4 of the smooch npm package. v4.5.1 Fixes this issue.